# "Data not in notebook; Store now"

Tags: warning-messages

I'm getting a "Data not in notebook; Store now" message. Where is this data stored? I looked at my working directory and found nothing.

I searched and could not find answer to this question on the forum.  I have the desktop with no cloud access.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is in the kernel (I'm guess you're getting this message the same way that I've seen it). Above a certain size limit (1MB), which you can set, the kernel will not transmit the data to the FE to be stored in the notebook, to keep the notebook from bloating. Click the button if you'd rather have a bloated notebook with all the data in it.

See

- [`$NotebookInlineStorageLimit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$NotebookInlineStorageLimit.html) (V12.1 or later) or
- [`$SummaryBoxDataSizeLimit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$SummaryBoxDataSizeLimit.html) (before V12.1)

for more.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to "unbloat"?  I did click it by accident (really out of curiosity)

Comment: You can delete the cell. If you don't want the data, I see no problem with that.

Comment: Thanks again!   [padding to meet min reqs]